# Refire CSS animation with javascript after a previous one is complete

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I was trying to use the new `animate()` function to refire a CSS animation. I'm using Chrome 48 but I wonder if this is even possible right now.

The animation should be just a growing and shrinking square. I've tried several things, as you can see, but none worked:

```js
var elem = document.querySelector(".box");

document.addEventListener("click", function() {
  elem.classList.add("close");
  elem.animate(); //not working
  elem.animate("grow"); //not working
  elem.animate([{
    transform: 'scale(1)'
  }, {
    transform: 'scale(0)'
  }], 1500); //not working
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #099;
  animation: grow 1s ease;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
.close {
  animation: grow 1s ease reverse;
}
@keyframes grow {
  from {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

The problem seems to be that when the first animation ends, the animation state of the element is "complete" (or something like that) so when you change the animation property, it is still complete, and it doesn't begin again. As the second animation should fire after an event, it can't be iterated.

Edit: I noticed that this works when if I click while the square is still growing!

**Edit2: I found out that if you just add the reverse property, the animation doesn't fire but if you change the time to a different value, or the animation name, it fires again!**

Comment: you can do this with pure CSS, but from your question i'm not sure if you're trying to create an infinate loop `animation-iteration-count:infinite;`

Comment: No, not infinite, this is more a simplified example, it should actually happen  when event fires. I've updated the example

Comment: @Vandervals: What exactly should happen when the event fires? Should the square shrink (animate) and then re-grow after the shrink is complete (or) should the square snap to `scale(0)` immediately and then re-grow?

Comment: @Harry the square should grow when loading and when the event happens it should shrink and remain like that.

Comment: @Vandervals: Ok, I can give the solution for this but before I do just one more question. If it shrinks and remains like that then you can't do any further actions because it would have no height/width. Is that ok (or) is this grow and shrink just a minimal example?

Comment: @Harry, this is just an example, the real element would change acording to an imput focus and blur events

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you had mentioned in the last paragraph of your question is spot on. Once an animation is set to an element and has executed completely, the browser/UA would continue to remember its state. That animation cannot be restarted (either in the same or reverse direction) unless the original animation is removed atleast for a split second.

For this, we need to introduce a delay (time-out) or force a repaint because without that if we remove and add just the classes alone within the same blocking call then UA would not see any difference. It would continue to think that the animation was never removed.

**For re-firing the same animation:**

To re-fire the same animation again when the a click is made anywhere in the document, just remove the existing animation's class and add it back again after a delay like in the below snippet.

```js
var elem = document.querySelector(".box");

document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  refireAnim("open");
});

function refireAnim(anim) {
  elem.classList.remove(anim);
  setTimeout(function() {
    elem.classList.add(anim);
  }, 0);
}
```

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #099;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
.open {
  animation: grow 1s ease;
}
@keyframes grow {
  from {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box open"></div>
```

---

**For re-firing the same animation in different direction:**

To re-fire the same animation again but in a different direction, remove and add the animation's class after a delay like in the above snippet and also change the direction.

```js
var elem = document.querySelector(".box")
  forward = true;

document.addEventListener("click", function() {
  refireAnim("open");
  if (forward) { /* change the direction based on state */
   elem.style["animation-direction"] = "reverse"; 
  }
  else {
   elem.style["animation-direction"] = null;
  }  
  forward = !forward; /* change the state */
});

function refireAnim(anim) {
  elem.classList.remove(anim);
  setTimeout(function() {
    elem.classList.add(anim);
  }, 0);
}
```

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #099;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
.open {
  animation: grow 1s ease forwards;
}
@keyframes grow {
  from {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class="box open"></div>
```

Or as you pointed out, force a repaint after the removal of the class but before its adding it again. (*This seems to avoid the flash on toggle*)

```js
var elem = document.querySelector(".box")
  forward = true;

document.addEventListener("click", function() {
  refireAnim("open");
  if (forward) { /* change the direction based on state */
   elem.style["animation-direction"] = "reverse"; 
  }
  else {
   elem.style["animation-direction"] = null;
  }  
  forward = !forward; /* change the state */
});

function refireAnim(anim) {
  elem.classList.remove(anim);
  elem.clientHeight;
  elem.classList.add(anim);
}
```

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #099;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
.open {
  animation: grow 1s ease forwards;
}
@keyframes grow {
  from {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class="box open"></div>
```

---

**For toggling one animation to another:**

Create two classes where one is for the open animation, another is for the close animation and toggle them on click such that there is a delay between removal of one class and addition of another.

```js
var trigger = document.querySelector("#toggle"),
  elem = document.querySelector(".box");

trigger.addEventListener("click", function() {
  currState = elem.className.split(" ")[1];
  newState = (currState == "open") ? "close" : "open";
  switchAnim(currState, newState);
});

function switchAnim(existingAnim, newAnim) {
  elem.classList.remove(existingAnim);
  setTimeout(function() {
    elem.classList.add(newAnim);
  }, 0);
}
```

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #099;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
.open {
  animation: grow 1s ease;
}
.close {
  animation: grow 1s ease reverse forwards;
}
@keyframes grow {
  from {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle" />
<div class="box open"></div>
```

As you had pointed out in comments, you could avoid the time-out and instead force the browser to do a repaint before adding the other animation's class also. (*This seems to avoid the flash on toggle*)

```js
var trigger = document.querySelector("#toggle"),
  elem = document.querySelector(".box");

trigger.addEventListener("click", function() {
  currState = elem.className.split(" ")[1];
  newState = (currState == "open") ? "close" : "open";
  switchAnim(currState, newState);
});

function switchAnim(existingAnim, newAnim) {
  elem.classList.remove(existingAnim);
  elem.clientHeight;
  elem.classList.add(newAnim);
}
```

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #099;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
.open {
  animation: grow 1s ease;
}
.close {
  animation: grow 1s ease reverse forwards;
}
@keyframes grow {
  from {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle" />
<div class="box open"></div>
```

The other way to avoid that flash (a brief period where the element reverts to its real height and width before being animated again) is to make use of transitions like in the below snippet.

```js
var trigger = document.querySelector("#toggle"),
  elem = document.querySelector(".box");

trigger.addEventListener("click", function() {
  elem.classList.toggle("close");
  elem.classList.toggle("open");
});


window.onload = function() {
  elem.classList.toggle("close");
  elem.classList.toggle("open");
}
```

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #099;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transition: all 1s;
}
.open {
  transform: scale(1);
}
.close {
  transform: scale(0);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle" />
<div class="box close"></div>
```

---

**Re-firing whatever animation exists on the element at a given point:**

The checkbox toggles the animation but whenever the document is clicked, whichever animation that is applicable depending on the checkbox's state will be ***re-fired***.

```js
var trigger = document.querySelector("#toggle"),
  elem = document.querySelector(".box");

document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target != trigger) {
    currState = elem.className.split(" ")[1];
    switchAnim(currState, currState);
  }
})

trigger.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (trigger.checked)
    switchAnim("close", "open");
  else
    switchAnim("open", "close");
});

function switchAnim(existingAnim, newAnim) {
  console.log(existingAnim);
  elem.classList.remove(existingAnim);
  setTimeout(function() {
    elem.classList.add(newAnim);
  }, 0);
}
```

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #099;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
.open {
  animation: grow 1s ease;
}
.close {
  animation: grow 1s ease reverse forwards;
}
@keyframes grow {
  from {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle" checked/>
<div class="box open"></div>
```

Comment: I know I'll sound a little picky but... Althought this is the best solution so far... I was asking to refire the animation, not change one animation for another one. Maybe it is not possible to refire it when it is complete... I noticed that my code worked if the click happens while the square is still growing!

Comment: It seems to get stoped when it ends. The class I add reverses the animation but imagine I just want to fire it again, no matter the current animation is. Is that possible? The aniamtion api has .play() .resume() methods, muy they don't seem to work... It would make sense tome that there would be a way to refire the animation of an element by something like: elem.play() or something.

Comment: What is the difference with the example in your post? (other than the refactoring) Also, I've tested this and instead of the timeout which generates a flash, it looks better if you use elem.clientHeight

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102623/discussion-between-vandervals-and-harry).

Comment: Good answer. Just as a side comment, in most browsers it works ok with a timeout of 0. It's setting the function in the queue and allowing a refresh what does the trick, not the timeout.

Comment: @Harry I noticed it is harder for changing directions but it is a lot easier (just adding a class) if you change time or animation name.

Comment: @Vandervals: Change of animation name is almost the same as changing class but I thought this wasn't what you needed based on your earlier comment - *not change one animation for another one*. If you change just time then it doesn't shrink, it should only refire the grow animation.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use settimeout, use the delay value
2. Don't mix CSS animations and JS animations, if you don't know what you are doing
3. Use an iterations value
4. Use the transform so, that they form a loop. Startvalue equals endvalue. Otherwise you will get steps (golden animation box2)

```js
var elem1 = document.querySelector(".box1");
var elem2 = document.querySelector(".box2");

elem1.animate([{
    transform: 'scale(0)'
  }, {
    transform: 'scale(1)'
  }, {
    transform: 'scale(0)'
  }], {
    duration: 1500,               
    iterations: 9999,
    delay: 0                    
});

elem2.animate([{
    transform: 'scale(0)'
  }, {
    transform: 'scale(1)'
  }], {
    duration: 1500,               
    iterations: 9999,
    delay: 0                    
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #099;
  animation: grow 1s ease;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}

.box2 {
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="box box1"></div>
<div class="box box2"></div>
```

Comment: I can't see this working applied to my example: http://codepen.io/vandervals/pen/VeGXJP

Answer (score 1):

Try this....

HTML

```
  <body>
    <div id="square"></div>
  </body>
```

JS

```
$("document").ready(function(){
  var elem = document.querySelector("#square");


  elem.classList.add("box");


  setInterval(function(){
  elem.classList.remove("box");
   elem.classList.add("boxSh");

  },1000)

});
```

CSS

```
 .box {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      background: #099;
      animation: grow 1s ease;
      transform-origin: 0 0;
    }
    .boxSh {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      background: #099;
      animation: shrink 1s ease;
      transform-origin: 0 0;
    }
    .close {
      animation: grow 1s ease reverse;
    }
    .sh{
      animation: shrink 1s ease reverse;
    }
    @keyframes grow {
      from {
        transform: scale(0);
      }
      to {
        transform: scale(1);
      }
    }

    @keyframes shrink {

      to {
        transform: scale(0);
      }
    }
```

[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/IzS7bk1glzCphLatfyay?p=preview)

Comment: a loop was not what I was looking for... I updated the question with more info